# ROS architecture [solved]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!
where you can learn about the architecture of ROS
mechanisms of interaction and how it works?
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11457/ros-architecture-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on ROS Answers with karma: 471 on 2011-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

you should read some articles on wiki: http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2011-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2011-10-09**:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview - that's what I was looking for:) Thanks!